# Power brick with a high pitched whine

Tags: troubleshooting

The powerbrick for my computer emits a high pitched whine. What could be causing the noise? Any way I can stop or reduce it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostriction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switching power supplies use an inductor which can emit high-frequency noise. You can't do much about it, apart from replacing it. You could try disassembling the unit and injecting hot-melt glue into the inductor windings. That might dampen the vibration.

Comment: could also be an electrolytic capacitor with a small leak, they tend to make roughly the same sound.

Comment: And finally, it might be ceramic caps which sound pretty loud in 10Khz range (on some dielectrics) :-)